# Can't install dbt-snowflake; "No module named 'cmake'"

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, cmake-modules

(Context: Barely a novice at Terminal, know some SQL, don't know Python)

I'm taking a course on dbt, have my own Snowflake set up, and I'm trying to install dbt-snowflake on Mac. Attempting to run:

`pip install dbt-snowflake`

This fails, and it returns:

`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/xxxx/course/venv/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
                from cmake import cmake
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
            error: command '/Users/xxxx/course/venv/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
      Failed to build pyarrow
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

`

- I once successfully changed Python version in virtual environment to 3.9 to see whether that was the problem (but I can't replicate how I changed it), that didn't solve the problem, and currently it's back to 3.11.
- Have installed multiple versions of snowflake (3.7, 3.9, 3.11). I don't really understand how this works in context of everything.
- I have tried deleting and recreating virtual environments (under same name, venv)
- uninstalled and reinstalled cmake (`pip install --upgrade cmake`); this is version 3.25.0

1. I don't understand how I can have cmake installed and be told there is no module named 'cmake'.
2. Is there a particular version of Python I should be running, and if so, how do I reliably change that in virtual environments and different directories?
3. EDIT TO ADDRESS A COMMENT: I installed Python versions via terminal `brew install python@3.9`

Comment: dbt doesn't support Python 3.11, and I've a similar error in that circumstance.  How did you change the version of python in the venv, because that's not always a trivial thing?  Generally knowing how you installed Python (and confirming that there are multiple versions installed) would help someone guide you to a solution.

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you how I changed the Python version. I looked up several stack overflow posts and basically inputted some commands, and one time I checked the Python version and it said 3.9. I should have taken note of the steps.